# Hi there,i have an error "'FutureOr<Response<dynamic>>', is a potentially non-nullable type."

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, dio

im calling a get response in Dio with my api,but i keep getting this error "'FutureOr<Response>', is a potentially non-nullable type." althoug i have returned a return statement in my get api function.

i add a return statement to it and im now tempted to downgrade flutter to help but before i do that i want to solve the issue first.

`

```
//finction for sending get request in the api
//error apears here on the get
  Future<Response> get(String _path, {Map<String, dynamic>? query}) async {
       
    try {
      
      String _url = '$_base_url$_path';
      Map<String, dynamic> _query = {
        'api_key': _api_key,
        'language': 'english',
      };
      if (query != null) {
        _query.addAll(query);
      }
      
      return await dio.get(
        _url,
        queryParameters: _query,
      );
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print('Unable to perform get request.');
      print('DioError: $e');
    }
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can think about this way. While the `try` blocks raise some issue, it will fail to return the response object.catch block is not returning anything.You can return error Reposone object here or just change return datatyoe to nullable Response.

```
 Future<Response?> get(
```

While using this method, do a null check.

```dart
final result = await get(...);
if(result !=null){...}
```

For FutureBuilder, use nullable dateType.

Comment: can you place demo an exmaple with the code above.Thank you

Comment: Are you using FutureBuilder or just tap method ?

Comment: im using a futureBuilder

Comment: Can you include that on question as well

Answer (score 0):

so after quite the number of research.what i had to do was to return the response.

```
return Response();
```